# Convert int to time Java

Tags: java, android

I have an `int` counter that starts at 600 and in a `Runnable` and is increased by 1.

600 represents 6 am, and 2400 represents midnight.

This `int` is compared to a `int` received from an API in the same format.

I need to compare them both; however, the problem is my `int` has 100 mins in an hour at the moment, so as time goes on it gets more and more out of time.

Is there a way to convert the `int` counter to a time format? (The Java format of 18000000 = 6am doesn't work)

Cheers Phil

Comment: "in a runnable is increased by 1" <-- how often?

Comment: Why are you doing it like this instead of Date/Time libraries?

Comment: currently it is running every 200 ms (200ms=1min)

Comment: Isn't this just math?

Comment: Let me guess... you increase the counter using `Thread.sleep(60000)`.

Comment: *"The Java format of 180000 = 6am"* Huh? Never seen such format, sorry.

Comment: sorry missed a few 0's..... and the runnable is called via a schedule

Comment: Pardon the odd question, but since when does 200ms equal a minute?

Comment: it doesnt, but in my app 200ms is equal to 1min real time, its sped up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave Newton is right by saying its just math. Your integer time is composed by two components, hours and minutes (which is easy to read but difficult to calculate).

```
 int time = 600;
 int hours = time / 100;
 int minutes = (time - hours * 100) % 60;
```

So you can't just increment your time (`time++`), because you end up with a houndred minutes per hour as you wrote. Use this method instead:

```
 int incrementTime(int time) {
      time++;
      int hours = time / 100;
      int minutes = (time - hours * 100) % 60;
      if (minutes == 0) hours++;
      return hours * 100 + minutes;
 }
```

You can try it out:

```
 time = 600;
 for (int i=0; i < 120; i++) {
      time = incrementTime(time);
      System.out.println(time);
 }
```

Comment: Excelent, just what i was looking for. i understood Dave saying it is just math, but couldn't figure it out in my head or put it down into working code. Thankyou very much! Phil

Answer (score 1):

If you do really need to transform your 0 --> 2400 to a "time format", you might use:

```
hour = uTime/100
uMinutes = uTime - hour*100
normalMinutes = (60*uMinutes)/100
```

Then go about changing to "long" and milliseconds for use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Java already has a way to convert a datetime to a number and vice versa.

```
//Get integer representation of time
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
long integerRepresentation = rightNow.getTimeInMillis();

//Set time to integer reprsentation
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar2.setTimeInMillis(integerRepresentation);
```